# Xcode Debugger: What does the blue italic text mean?

Tags: c++, objective-c, xcode

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

Clearly it indicates that the x coordinate of my struct differs from the y coordinate, however their values are the same. How do they differ?

While we're at it... This one should be easier... What does the capital L icon indicate?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The blue italic text means that the value of that variable (or expression) has changed since the last time the program paused.

“L” in the green square means that `c` is a local variable.  “A” in a purple square means a function or method argument (e.g. you will see this next to `self`).  “V” in a green square means some other type of variable, like an instance variable or a global variable.  There may be others but I don't remember them.

Answer (score 0):

The 'L' stands for local variable. Take a look at the Variables Pane section in the [Xcode User Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode_User_Guide/060-Debug_and_Tune_Your_App/debug_app.html). I would imagine the blue font would stand for the expected value before the lines get executed or when you reached your breakpoint.