# What is the different between blue and black color at debug mode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, debugging, swift

Why sometimes the text is blue and sometimes black?

[image]

[image]

Comment: The difference between blue and black? `0000ff`, or 1 if you allow for wraparound :-) May be related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18798121/xcode-4-6-debugger-what-does-the-blue-italic-text-mean

Comment: I guess blue color text is a link or something which can show location. Never tried this.

Comment: Does it mean the value changed in previous debug step?

Comment: yes I guess it mean that the value changed like you said. thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm very curious with this question, and did small test.

I'm not sure the thing which I have observed was right or not, but I did test it many times and got the same result.

**Conclusion:**

I observed that when you debug code and a variable on which pop up screen appears if it is still in use I mean existence of that variable is important to compiler than it will show **black text**. But after the value of that variable is no more required by compiler than it will shows **blue text**.

For an example:

[image]

In above image variable `fileName` is used in second line (it is not visible because pop up screen overlaps it, you can see it in next image) by a string variable so the text here is black for now. But see the next image

[image]

Here you can see that variable `fileName` is not used any more and debug pointer is at the end of the method. So the text becomes blue now.

Even in console window text is changing as per variable existence.

**Reference to first image console screen:**

[image]

**Reference to second image console screen:**

[image]